# Rectifying zonal statistics processing error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am attempting to use the zonal statistics tool of QGIS v. 2.18.10.

I am overlaying a vector layer containing zones on a raster layer that
contains temperature data. When I use a climate raster layer from
WorlClim (http://worldclim.org/version2) everything works as expected.

However, when I use a climate raster layer from:

https://utexas.app.box.com/v/Xavier-etal-IJOC-DATA

I receive the process does not run and I receive the error message:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' See log for
more details
```

Where is the 'log'?